# Eccentricity of a general ellipse

Tags: conic-sections

How to find the eccentricity of an ellipse $5x^2 + 5y^2 + 6xy = 8$ ?.

I tried it by factorizing it into the distance form for a line and point but I failed. Please help

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the quickest way to do it, but you can rotate it by $45^\circ$ with the substitution
\begin{align}
x&=\frac{X+Y}{\sqrt2}\\
y&=\frac{-X+Y}{\sqrt2}\,,
\end{align}
and as long as you know how to get the eccentricity of $a^2X^2+b^2Y^2=c^2$, you’re ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

The eccentricity of an ellipse with semi-major axis $a$ and semi-minor axis $b$ is $\sqrt{1-b^2/a^2}$.  For an ellipse given by a quadratic equation
$$ (x,y) V \pmatrix{x\cr y\cr} = 1$$ where $V$ is a positive definite symmetric matrix, the semi-major and semi-minor axes are the square roots
of the reciprocals of the eigenvalues of $V$.  In this case your matrix is
$$ \pmatrix{5/8 & 3/8\cr 3/8 & 5/8\cr}$$
and its eigenvalues are $1$ and $1/4$.

Comment: Sorry sir i dont have a slightest clue to what you have done. Please can you do it by other method as i am not familiar with matrices